# Google Maps Android Undo Marker Drag

Tags: android, google-maps, drag, marker, undo

I am trying to add an undo functionality to my code. However, when I tried to get my marker's position in `onMarkerDragStart`, it does not give me the position of marker but, it gives a little bit upper of this position, so when I tried to undo changes and locate my marker to previous location, it is not located there but upper of this point.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, seems like there are no way but to create your own logic to keep track of all your markers position.

At first I through there might be a relationship between the zoom level and old+ new position, but it seems to me that the new position is kind of random.